# Render checkboxes in For in loop and bind their Values in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create some filters to filter data from the database using a combination of the more than one checkbox. Something like this.

[image]

I am getting redirected from a landing page to this page where properties are listed with some get variables. in my case, I have 3 get variables in this request.
$location, $type and $price.
Now I want whatever location is in $location variable the checkbox should be checked which has the same value as $location.
In my case for instance: if my $location == candolim then candolim checkbox should be checked automatically.

Then using that I will send an AJAX request to the server to fetch properties.
Now here I am using Laravel and Vue Js. Axios for requests.

So initially when I got redirected here from landing page search filter; in the request has variables called $locaton, $type and $price.
Here I am using Vue js. whenever the page is loaded and Vue Instance is created I am fetching all the locations available in the database and displaying them here with checkboxes.
so here is how I am displaying that:

```
   <p>SEARCH BY LOCATION</p>
<span v-for="item in allLocations">
<input type="checkbox"> <span class="checkbox-label"> @{{item.location}} </span> <br>
</span>
<hr>
```

So now my question is How can I get the value of every checkbox which is clicked using Vue?
And how can I check a checkbox which has value same as $location which I am getting from the landing page using get request?

I know guys this question is very confusing but this is how i can explain what i want. 
Please help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply keep all the values to be selected in an array field in `data`, e.g. `selectedLocations`, then for each checkbox set the `value` property to the corresponding value that has to make the checkbox selected and use the same `selectedLocations` as the `v-model` for each checkbox.

It is explained in the [Form Input Bindings - Checkbox](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) section of the guide.

#### Demo

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    allLocations: [
      { location: 'candolim' },
      { location: 'baga' },
    ],
    selectedLocations: [ 'candolim' ]     // you can set this from your $location (but make sure selectedLocations is an array)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <p>SEARCH BY LOCATION</p>
  <span v-for="item in allLocations">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="item.location" v-model="selectedLocations"> <span class="checkbox-label"> {{item.location}} </span> <br>
  </span>
  <hr>
  <span>Selected locations: {{ selectedLocations }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the answer. It's working but still, I didn't get an answer to my another question. if I am getting any one location in a PHP variable then I want to be checked that checkbox. for example. here if my $location == candolim then I need my checkbox to be checked. Thanks.

Comment: Which is the other question? If you want the value of the checkboxes, it is kept in `selectedLocations` as an array. If you want to send it to php, you have to send it for example through a form or with `FormData`.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much) It helped me so much.

Comment: It doesn't  work when I push new object  into array,it return null?